# Expression Engine i18n

Tags: internationalization, expressionengine

Does Expression Engine have a built-in solution for i18n (internationalization)?

I have to build a multi-language site, and would like to know the best approaches in EE for doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways you can create a multilingual or country-specific site in ExpressionEngine to deliver content *specific to each language/country*.

The two most popular solutions are summarized from the following ExpressionEngine Wiki articles:

#### [MultiLingual Websites in ExpressionEngine](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Multi_language_site/)

The basic idea is to present your content in different languages using a combination of URL Segments, custom fields and a bit of PHP.

**Advantages**

- Single entry manages multiple languages
- Simple URL structure

As an example, say you have a 3-language site: English (en), Spanish (es) and German (de).

For every piece of content in your site, you'd create a custom field with the language identifier as a postfix (or prefix, whatever you prefer) to the fields.

Your custom field names might look like this:

```
custom_field_en
custom_field_es
custom_field_de
```

To switch between languages, simply add a corresponding URL segment (`/en`, `/es` or `/de`) that matches the language:

```
example.com/template_group/template/en
example.com/template_group/template/es
example.com/template_group/template/de
```

**The main advantage of this approach is that it keeps all versions of your content inside a single entry, making updates and edits easy and consistent.**

---

### [MultiLingual Websites in ExpressionEngine, Alternative](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Multi_language_site_alternative/)

The alternative approach idea is to *create sub-directories for each country*, and use ExpressionEngine's `path.php` Global Variables to hold the country code and/or language as a variable.

**Advantages**

- No PHP needed
- No need to keep track of which segment holds the language variable
- Elegant URL structure

Using the same 3-languages as an example from the first method, you would create a new directory in the root of your EE install and name it after the country code of the language you want to add:

Your folder structure might look like this:

```
+ /de
+ /en
+ /es
index.php
+ /images
+ /system
+ /themes
```

To allow this method work, place a copy of the main `index.php` inside each of the language directories. You would then modify each file by assigning variables corresponding to each language's directory:

```
$assign_to_config['site_index'] = 'http://www.example.com/en/';
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array(
    "country_code" => "en",
    "language" => "english"
);
```

The URLs built will use whatever language/country designation you choose:

```
example.com/es-MX/template_group/template/
example.com/MX/template_group/template/
```

**The main advantage of the alternative approach is using Global Variables, leveraging the fact they are are parsed very early, and can be used almost anywhere in templates.**

See: [ExpressionEngine's Parse Order](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf) (PDF, 33 KB)

---

### Other Solutions

Embracing the philosophy of ExpressionEngine, the flexibility you're given as a designer/developer allows you to tailor a custom solution that suits your unique needs.

If either of these approaches don't quite meet your needs, you can eaily craft your own method or take a hybrid approach.

With this in mind, a good starting point would be to look into the [Multilingual Add-Ons at Devot-ee](http://devot-ee.com/search/tags/tag/language/) that may aide in your development.

Comment: All the wiki links are dead by now. I couldn't easily find replacement links. If someone else has them it would be great to update this post.